# ArcGIS integration with Java

Tags: ejb, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-runtime

I am new to ArcGIS. I understand ArcGIS can be integrated by various tools and methods. The widgets we need to create are mostly custom widgets. We used web app builder to build the custom widgets. We have to integrate with EJB's for data population. Not interested to convert EJB's to rest services.

What is the better approach to integrate ArcGIS with EJB?

1. Build custom widgets using web app builder and integrate with EJB's using Spring/Servlets and jQuery.
2. Build ArcGIS maps and custom widgets with ArcGIS runtime SDK for Java

Comment: The ArcGIS Runtime license doesn't allow you to use Runtime in server code, so the second option is probably out.

Answer (score 0):

#2 is not an option, as ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Java is for JavaSE/JavaFX client development, and the business model prohibits its use in server containers. Unfortunately.

#1 is your best approach.

Also, you may want to investigate https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java.